# Is one large home network superior to two separate ones?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, home-networking, wireless-access-point, wired-networking

I have a [Plusnet Hub One](https://www.broadbandchoices.co.uk/guides/hardware/plusnet-hub-one) as my primary router/modem for all of the home's wired and wireless connections. In an attempt to increase the range and speeds when connecting to the internet upstairs, I'm planning to connect a second router (a [TP-LINK Archer C50](https://static.tp-link.com/2018/201802/20180201/7106507914_Archer%20C50A5(EU)_QIG_V4.pdf)) to the first via an Ethernet cable.

To my understanding, once this connection is established and any IP address/DHCP range conflicts have been addressed, both routers will show up as two distinct networks.

As per [step 4 of this guide](https://www.expertreviews.co.uk/networks/1401371/how-to-extend-wi-fi-range-increase-speed-and-fix-problems/page/0/5), the routers can then optionally be merged into the one network by simply changing the new router's SSID and settings to reflect that of the old one.

Which of these choices should I opt for if I want the fastest speeds with the best signal throughout the house? Are the speed and signal strength of the two networks combined likely to be the same as they are separately?

Comment: Also, what channels should I select for each of the four separate connections (Plusnet 2.4GHz, Plusnet 5.GHz, TP-LINK 2.4GHz, TP-LINK 5.GHz)? I really don't want to fudge this up.

Comment: You should [edit] that into the question, instead of posting a comment.

Comment: @3D1T0R It's basically a question of its own, which is why I just asked it separately [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1386400/which-wifi-channels-should-i-set-for-a-two-router-4-network-setup). If you can answer it, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Ah, OK. I don't feel like taking the time to write up a proper answer to that right now, but basically what it boils down to is that it doesn't matter which channel you pick, but you'll get better performance on a channel that isn't in use by another device, so you want to pick different channels for each access point, and first analyze the WiFi spectrum around so you can choose channels that don't already have other WiFi signals (e.g. your neighbor's WiFi) on them.