# Which WiFi channels should I use for a two-router, 4-network setup?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, home-networking, wireless-access-point, wifi-configuration

As a follow-on from [this question here](https://superuser.com/questions/1386062/is-one-large-home-network-superior-to-two-separate-ones), I've decided to go ahead and try merging my four networks (two routers, 2 bands each, in the UK) into two (one for each band) to see how performance is affected.

I know that the way to merge the networks is to give the new router's 2.4GHz and 5GHz networks the same SSID and security settings as the original router's 2.4GHz and 5GHz networks respectively. However, the part that I'm wary of is which WiFi channel each of the four connections should be set to.

A guideline of this is pointed out in step 9 of [this article](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/setting-up-wireless-routers-same-ssid-68675.html), but that says nothing of networks with two separate bands. On the other hand, step 4 of [this article](https://www.expertreviews.co.uk/networks/1401371/how-to-extend-wi-fi-range-increase-speed-and-fix-problems/page/0/5) does mention that bands need to have channels of their own, but gives no actual numbers.

With that in mind, what's a good guideline for which channels to set each network (Plusnet 2.4GHz, Plusnet 5GHz, TP-LINK 2.4GHz, TP-LINK 5GHz) to avoid  or diminish interference? I've spent a lot of time setting up this network, and I would hate to throw it all away by configuring it wrong.

Comment: I'm guessing the answer may change depending on whether you're in an apartment block with 50 other wifi sources within 100m, or out in the country...

Comment: @Tetsujin Somewhere in between, but I'm not really interested in determining the most optimal channels based on the neighbours' networks, I just want to be sure that neither of these 4 interfere with each other.

Comment: networks interfere if they're in close proximity - by channel & geographical distance. The network they are connected to is not an important part of that distinction.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you're in the USA and have no neighbors in range, then set your three 2.4 GHz bands to use (1,6,11) , which don't overlap each other.  https://www.metageek.com/training/resources/why-channels-1-6-11.html .  The 5GHz band doesn't overlap the others.

If you do have neighbors in range, then you can use an Android or iPhone app to determine which channels are already used, and avoid those.  Same-channel networks are strong noise to each other, near-channel networks are mild noise, and far-channel (1,6,11) networks don't affect each other.

If you're outside the USA, you may have more channels available.

Comment: I'm from the UK. Is there any way to determine what channels are available?

Comment: more channels, but 13 doesn't *quite* stretch to be out of reach of 11, so your 'basic' 3 is still a good rule if you're not 'neighbour dodging' :)

Comment: @Hashim , you mentioned in prior comments that you weren't interested in the neighbor's network, so just use 1,6,11 .

Comment: Sorry, I made a small mistake in the original answer: each of the two routers has a 2.4GHz and 5GHz band, so there are two of each band. It sounds like this would change the answer significantly.

Comment: @Hashim , therefore it's even easier than as originally answered.  Just use non-overlapping channels at opposite ends of the available spectrum, assuming that no other networks are nearby.  I'm not certain where the misunderstanding is.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage Do all 4 not need to have a unique channel?

Comment: https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/connectivity/wifi-ieee-802-11/channels-frequencies-bands-bandwidth.php has charts of 2.4GHz and 5GHz channels showing frequencies, so you can see there's no overlap between 2.4GHz and 5GHz channels. You can bond multiple channels together for more bandwidth https://wifijedi.com/2009/01/25/how-stuff-works-channel-bonding/ in the 5GHz band in the UK https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2016/05/ofcom-wi-fi-faster-in-the-uk-5ghz-80mhz-channels/ , so don't set up the PlusNet & TP-Link 5GHz routers on immediately adjacent channels.

Comment: @Hashim , yes, one at the bottom of the 2.4 GHz, one at the top of the 2.4 GHz, one at the bottom of 5 GHz, one at the top of 5 GHz.

Comment: @K7AAY and Christopher - after properly looking at [this link](https://www.metageek.com/training/resources/design-dual-band-wifi.html), I now realise that the sizes (?) of 5GHz channels are entirely different to those of 2.4GHz, so this starts to fall into place now. I'd assumed they were the same. Stupid, I know, but it's been a long few days. To clarify, am I correct in thinking that something like the following setup would work well for me: one 2.4GHz network on channel 1, one 2.4GHz network on channel 11, one 5GHz network on channel 36, one 5.GHz on channel 48? Am I still miss something?

Comment: Both 1 and 11, and 36 and 48 represent the lowest and highest respective numbers I can assign for each band, which I think is what you were referring to by "one at the bottom" and "one at the top", Christopher.

Comment: In your case, since you are in the UK, you can use channels 1 and 13.

Comment: _Christopher_, please feel free to incorporate any of the links I found to reinforce your answer, should you find that useful.